# Running a string array inside the include method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I created an array named itemNameAreaReplace containing the regions I needed to find.

How do I use this inside the include() method?

So if it matches with the word 'UK' I could store that and replace it in every input[name=item_name] with 'Europe' or something else.

```js
const itemName = $(".postal input[name=item_name]");
const itemNameAreaReplace = ['UK', 'EUROPE', 'AMERICA', 'REST OF WORLD'];

console.log(itemName.val());

$("#selectArea").change(function() {

  const selectedArea = $(this).val();

  const replace = () => {
    if (itemName.val().includes('UK')) {
      console.log("Replacing UK with Europe...");
      itemName.val(itemName.val().replace('UK', 'Europe'));
      console.log(itemName.val());
    } else {
      console.log("Replacing Europe with UK...");
      itemName.val(itemName.val().replace('Europe', 'UK'));
      console.log(itemName.val());
    }
  };
  
  replace();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="selectArea" name="selectArea">
  <option value="post-uk" selected="selected">UK</option>
  <option value="post-eu">Europe</option>
  <option value="post-am">USA, South America and Canada</option>
  <option value="post-rw">Rest of World - Asia, Japan, Australia</option>
</select>

<form class="postal 0" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <!-- Change UK -->
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="(ABC) - UK - Product" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you bring a short version of your question?  I like to help but it too long to read

Comment: as comment above - most of your code does not appear to be related to the question (hidden email fields?), more info here [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I'm basically trying to replace the value of item_name, but only a single word. So for example, if the selected option says Japan, then the item_name will say 'ABC  - Japan - Product', instead of 'ABC - UK - Product'.

Comment: I've edited the post. I'm really sorry, I'm not a good communicator.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. There is no japan option.. Can you describe the problem with steps to reproduce? For example: Choose 2nd option, the log should be: `abc` but I get `xyz`.

Comment: *"How do I use this inside the include() method"* - short answer: you don't.  `string.include()` will only take another string.  You have options, from simple loop through `itemNameAreaReplace`, to converting the array to a regex; or an over-engineered process such as splitting your text by space into an array and doing a join.

Comment: Thank you Freedom! Your post gave me an idea. I'll post my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a loop that scans for a matching string in the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Searches for the input in every form.
  const itemName = $(".postal input[name=item_name]");

  // Array of regions.
  const getShippingRegion = ['UK', 'EUROPE', 'AMERICA', 'JAPAN', 'REST OF WORLD'];

  // Stores new region string.
  let shippingRegion;

  // Log the current value of itemName.
  console.log(itemName.val());

  // Detects when the selected option's change.
  $("#selectArea").change(function() {

    // Stores the current option's value.
    const selectedArea = $(this).val();

    // If-Else - Gives shippingRegion its new string.
    switch (selectedArea) {
      case 'post-uk':
        shippingRegion = 'UK';
        break;
      case 'post-eu':
        shippingRegion = 'EUROPE'
        break;
      case 'post-am':
        shippingRegion = 'AMERICA'
        break;
      case 'post-jp':
        shippingRegion = 'JAPAN'
        break;
      case 'post-rw':
        shippingRegion = 'REST OF WORLD'
        break;
      default:
        console.log('Error');
    }

    // Function - Replaces the input's value based on the selected option.
    const replace = () => {

      // Checks each string in the array.
      for (let i = [0]; i < getShippingRegion.length; i++) {

        // If the input's value finds any of the string from the array...
        if (itemName.val().includes(getShippingRegion[i])) {

          // ... replace the selected string from shippingRegion.
          itemName.val(itemName.val().replace(getShippingRegion[i], shippingRegion));

        }

      }

    };

    // Run the function above.
    replace();

    // Log the new value.
    console.log(itemName.val());

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper">

  <span><strong>Please select your area below:</strong></span>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="selectArea" name="selectArea">
      <option value="post-uk" selected="selected">UK</option>
      <option value="post-eu">Europe</option>
      <option value="post-am">USA, South America and Canada</option>
      <option value="post-jp">Japan</option>
      <option value="post-rw">Rest of World - Asia, Japan, Australia</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <form class="postal 0" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="(ABC) - UK - Product Name" />
  </form>

</div>
```